# Varying 0-1px gap between div background and border on High-DPI displays

Tags: css, google-chrome, retina-display, dpi

Here is an isolated example of a button I've created in CSS. It features a 1px border with a gradient, and a background gradient. The background gradient is implemented as a pseudo-element to allow its opacity to be faded on hover.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wbYoeo?editors=1100

```
.Button
{
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0.8rem;
    border-style: solid;
    border-image: linear-gradient(
        to right,
        green 0%,
        blue 100%);
    border-image-slice: 1;
    border-width: 1px;
    position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
    transition: color 0.2s;
}

.Button::before
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        to right,
        green 0%,
        blue 100%);
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
```

The button doesn't render identically between monitors of differing DPI. Screenshots of the button rendered in Chrome on Windows with varying DPI scales:

[100% DPI-scaled monitor, rendering correctly with no gap.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooK61.png)

[150% DPI-scaled monitor, showing a gap between the background and border.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZhCt.png)

[175% DPI-scaled monitor, showing a gap between the background and border.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ny7zT.png)

[200% DPI-scaled monitor, rendering correctly with no gap.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFPnR.png)

I've tried several strategies to render the button, but they all result in the gap:

- Tried using an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKjDi.png) with a gradient instead of `linear-gradient` on both the `border-image` and `background-image`.
- Tried to use an explicit div for the background gradient instead of a pseudo element.
- Tried to use an explicit div for the background gradient instead of a pseudo element, and also used a solid left and right border and ::before and ::after pseudo-elements with linear-gradient backgrounds for the top and bottom borders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Cause?

I would take an (uneducated) guess that this is caused by sub-pixels when scaling. It can't be a fraction of a pixel, so it chooses a whole pixel value; the parent's calculated value is 1px bigger than the value given to the children at some scales.

#### Workaround

Take the border off the button div itself, and put it on an `::after` pseudo-element so the border and background are both children. The border now appears to scale consistently with the background gradient.

**Example**

```css
.Button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.8rem;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
  transition: color 0.2s;
}

.Button::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, green 0%, blue 100%);
  opacity: 0.2;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

.Button:hover::before {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.Button:active::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.Button::after {
  content: '';
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient( to right, green 0%, blue 100%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  border-width: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
}

body {
  background: black;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
Click it:
<div class="Button"></div>
```